# Suggestions for FX Libraries for Promos

Tags: sfx, television, post-production

Hey guys,

Any suggestions for decent libraries of whooshes and transitions?

Alot of the stuff we have in our library currently is very Sci Fi/a bit mental, I would love to snap up a kit of useable sounds for spotting promos and corporate videos (plainer, more pedestrian stuff) so i don't have to create a sound for every spot like I do currently, far too time consuming for those shorter promo sessions.

Many thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi :)

Have a look on Boom Library Cinematic Trailers Designed [here](http://boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/index.php/store/cinematic-trailers).

Answer (score 2):

There's this one library called big whoosh. Can't remember if that one is more over the top or not, so look for some samples to listen to first. It takes a bit more effort, but for more "tame" whooshes I've often had luck with arrow whiz bys and whooshes intended for fight sounds. Sometimes you want to pitch them down a touch and give them a little verb. You could find these sorts of recordings prbably in a general fx library, a mini library of medieval combat fx, or a la carte on a site like sound dogs. Just design a whole bunch ahead of time and keep them on hand.